# Creating signal series for algorithmic trading

Tags: python

I have a list of data which looks like this:

```
signal = [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
```

Whereby a -1 pertains to a sell signal and a 1 pertains to a buy signal. 
I'd now like to transform this signal list to look like the following:

```
signal = [-1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0]
```

Which basically entails that if the direction of the signal has not changed from the previous signal (or it is already 0), that it should be 0.

I could not find any similar answers so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another flavor, based on list comprehension:

```
[j if i != j else 0 for i,j in zip([0] + signal, signal)]
#[-1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
_list = []
signal = [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
_list.append(signal[0])
for i in range(1,len(signal)):
    if signal[i] == signal[i-1]:
        _list.append(0)
    else:
        _list.append(signal[i])
signal = _list
print(signal)
```

Output: `[-1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0]`

Comment: can also check for `0` in the `if` part : `if signal[i] == signal[i-1] or signal[i] == 0:`

Comment: You should never call a variable `list`. `list` is a built-in function.